# Параллельное выполнение первого потока вместе с другими

Tags: java, многопоточность, spring, spring-mvc

Нужно вернуть json в котором находятся ссылки 5000+ файлов.
Cоздаю модель

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new JsonHelper().createModelAndJson(url);
return modelAndView;
```

В классе `JsonHelper` создается поток, в котором содержится List файлов и заполняется модель файлами.

```
 public ModelAndView createModelAndJson(String url) {

    JsonThread jsonThread = new JsonThread(url);
    Thread mainThread = new Thread(jsonThread);
    mainThread.start();
    try {
        mainThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonThread.getModelAndView();
}
```

Поиск файлов так же идёт в потоках дальше. В итоге показывает всё корректно, но одновременного выполнения нет у первого потока, все остальные потоки отрабатывают параллельно и показывают результат сразу. Т.е первый созданный запрос работает отдельно от остальных и их запуск тормозит.

Answer (score 0):

Метод `join` блокирует выполнение текущего потока до тех пор, пока `mainThread` не завершит работу. Таким образом выполнение вашего кода является последовательным.

Comment: Вообщем косяк был внутри mainTread. Пытался просто sleep поток, и они все одинаково засыпают и не тормозит их первый поток. В итоге. Я его сделал не потоком. А просто объектом с методом который тоже самое выполняет. Т.е если раньше на каждый запрос от пользователя создавался поток, который дальше плодит потоки. У меня создается объект который тоже плодит потоки